# Error while connecting to SQL Server using Java Spring Framework-Could not load JDBC driver class

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, spring-framework-beans

I am trying to connect to sql server database and access its table. I am using Java and springframework. I am getting the following error

`Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]`

The code is :

The bean.xml file has the properties defind as this

```xml
<bean id="sqldatasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://servername;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=dbname"/> 
  <property name="username" value="name"/>
  <property name="password" value="pwd"/>
</bean>
```

I am depending on 4 information here. All highlighted in bold. The screenshot below shows the server name, username and pwd. This is using microsoft sql server mgmt studio and the db name is found under databases.

[image]

I have gone through a couple of online articles. Do I need a hostname or port for this? Or just the servername and db name is sufficient. Is there anything else missing in the bean.xml file?
Do let me know and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand  the exception message?

Comment: The screenshot you provided is not visible, please edit your question. Regarding your question, did you import the Microsoft JDBC Driver For SQL Server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429334/cannot-load-driver-class-com-microsoft-jdbc-sqlserver-sqlserverdriver)

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your comments. Seems like this question has been closed. However the linked shared doesnot resolve the question. I will be resubmitting the question.